# Determine all real values of $p$ for which the following series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine all real values of  $p$ for which the following series converges:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\sin(n)|^p$.

I have to show that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n)^p$ is absolutely convergent. I am not sure how to do this because I usually go from a series to proving that it must converge since it is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outline: The series does not converge, because the terms don't have limit $0$.

To show $|\sin(n)|$ does not have limit $0$, suppose that for some integer $n$ we have $|\sin(n)|\lt 0.01$. Consider $\sin(n+1)=\sin(n)\cos(1)+\cos(n)\sin(1)$. The term $\sin(n)\cos(1)$ has quite small absolute value, while $\cos(n)\sin(1)$ has fairly large absolute value, so $|\sin(n+1)|$ is well away from $0$.

Comment: Why must it have limit zero?

Comment: It is a standard theorem that if $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$. (As you know, the converse does not hold, example $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n}$.) This gives us an easy but often overlooked divergence test: If the limit of the $a_n$ does not exist, or exists but is non-zero, then the series does not converge.

Comment: I think this needs to be more rigorous right?

Comment: Also are you saying that since the series must diverge, it also must be absolutely divergent?

Comment: The term *absolutely divergent* is not in common use.  The series already involves only non-negative terms, so the possibility of conditional convergence doesn't even arise. The series diverges for every $p$. because for any $n$, $|\sin(n)|^p$ does not have limit $0$, indeed does not have a limit at all, though we don't need to prove that. Unless the limit is $0$ we have divergence. (In the answer, I dealt with $|\sin(n)|$ only, since it is clear that if this does not have limit $0$, then neither does $|\sin(n)|^p$/)